# How to Automatically Center the Last Line of the Contents of a Minipage for Every Minipage in a Document

Tags: macros, horizontal-alignment, minipage, line, center

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\Large
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{5.65in} %\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}% 
\textbf{I would like to center the last line of the content of this minipage. The next minipage accomplishes this only for that minipage.}
\end{minipage}

\vspace*{25pt}

\fbox{
\begin{minipage}{5.65in}\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}% 
\textbf{By inserting the above string of commands next to $\{$5.65$\}$ accomplishes the task for this particular minipage.}
\end{minipage}
}

\vspace*{45pt}

\begin{minipage}{5.65in} %\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}% 
\textbf{But I would like to automatically center the last line of the contents of a minipage environment---for all such minipages in a document---without continually having to insert the aforesaid series of commands that does it only for the minipage to which it is applied.}
\end{minipage}

\vspace*{25pt}

\begin{minipage}{5.65in} %\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}% 
\textbf{But I would like to automatically center the last line of the contents of a minipage environment---for all such minipages in a document---without continually having to insert the aforesaid series of commands that does it only for the minipage to which it is applied.}
\end{minipage}

\vspace*{25pt}

\begin{minipage}{5.65in} %\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}% 
\textbf{But I would like to automatically center the last line of the contents of a minipage environment---for all such minipages in a document---without continually having to insert the aforesaid series of commands that does it only for the minipage to which it is applied.}
\end{minipage}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

It produces the output:

[image]

I would like to automatically center the last line of a minipage content for every minipage in a given document. The series of commands `\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}%`  accomplishes the centering only for the minipage to which it is applied.

If a document has, say, 100 such minipages, I would like be able to avoid having to apply the said series of commands 100 times.

QUESTION: (i) How may I automatically center the last line of a minipage output without having to resort to applying the said series of commands to each minipage environment in the document? (ii) Also, if there is one minipage out of the many that I do not want the last line centered, how may I prevent the centering from being applied to that particular minipage?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a new command with your setup and one optional parameter (the width of the minipage, default= 5.65in)

In this case `\Xmini[<width>]{<content>}` will insert the requested `minipage` with the last line of `content` centered.

If in particular case you do not want to apply it, use the normal minipage.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\newcommand{\Xmini}[2][5.65in]{% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\begin{minipage}{#1}\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}%
#2%
\end{minipage}  
}

\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \Large
    \begin{center}
        \begin{minipage}{5.65in} %\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}% 
            \textbf{I would like to center the last line of the content of this minipage. The next minipage accomplishes this only for that minipage.}
        \end{minipage}
        
        \vspace*{25pt}
        
        \fbox{
            \begin{minipage}{5.65in}\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}% 
                \textbf{By inserting the above string of commands next to $\{$5.65$\}$ accomplishes the task for this particular minipage.}
            \end{minipage}
        }
        
        \vspace*{45pt}
        
        \Xmini{%
            \textbf{But I would like to automatically center the last line of the contents of a minipage environment---for all such minipages in a document---without continually having to insert the aforesaid series of commands that does it only for the minipage to which it is applied.}
        }
        
        \vspace*{25pt}
        
            \Xmini[4in]{%
         \small \emph{But I would like to automatically center the last line of the contents of a minipage environment---for all such minipages in a document---without continually having to insert the aforesaid series of commands that does it only for the minipage to which it is applied.}
        }
        
        \vspace*{25pt}
        
    \Xmini[3in]{%
            \sffamily But I would like to automatically center the last line of the contents of a minipage environment---for all such minipages in a document---without continually having to insert the aforesaid series of commands that does it only for the minipage to which it is applied.
    }
        
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks @Simon Dispa. This works quite nicely; and, as you point out, if I don't need it for a particular minipage---I can simply use the standard minipage command. Thank you for answering both parts of the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
 \g@addto@macro\@minipagerestore{\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}}
```